# Vue 2 - using components inside components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code:
import './menu-item';
import ItemImage from "./item-image";

```
Vue.component('quest-card', {
    props: {
        title: String,
        isFree: Boolean,
        points: Number,
        item: String,
        level: Number,
    },
    components: {
        ItemImage
    },
    methods: {
        showFree: function() {
            return !!+this.isFree;
        },
    },
    template: `
      <section class="quest-reward bg-dark">
      <div class="rewardLevel">{{ level }}</div>
      <div v-if="!showFree()" class="bg-success freeReward">FREE</div>
      <div class="rewardItem">
        <item-image name="item" heb-name="test" rarity="epic"></item-image>
      </div>
      </section>
    `,
})
```

My component are used in a legacy HTML/JQuery website using selector (for this one - <quest-card ...> and it's not rendered with the item-image component:

[image]

Item image component looks like this:

```
const ItemImage = Vue.component('ItemImage', {
    props: ['name','heb-name', {
        rarity: {
            default: 'normal',
            type: String,
        }
    }],
    computed: {
      glowClass: () => {
          return `glow-${this.rarity}`;
        }
    },
    template: `
      <img v-bind:src="'images/items/' + item + '.png'" v-bind:class="glowClass"/>
    `,
})

export default ItemImage;
```

the export default of the Vue component seem wrong, but not sure what I have to do so they can play together. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had problems in defining the props

```js
const ItemImage = Vue.component('ItemImage', {
    props: {name: String, 'heb-name': String, item: [String, Number], rarity: {
            default: 'normal',
            type: String,
        }},
    computed: {
      glowClass: () => {
          return `glow-${this.rarity}`;
        }
    },
    template: `
      <img v-bind:src="'images/items/' + item + '.png'" v-bind:class="glowClass"/>
    `,
})

Vue.component('quest-card', {
    props: {
        title: String,
        isFree: Boolean,
        points: Number,
        item: String,
        level: Number,
    },
    components: {
        ItemImage
    },
    methods: {
        showFree: function() {
            return !!+this.isFree;
        },
    },
    template: `
      <section class="quest-reward bg-dark">
      <div class="rewardLevel">{{ level }}</div>
      <div v-if="!showFree()" class="bg-success freeReward">FREE</div>
      <div class="rewardItem">
        <item-image name="item" heb-name="test" rarity="epic"></item-image>
      </div>
      </section>
    `,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<div id="app"><quest-card /></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```